# Uniform continuity of two functions

Tags: functions, uniform-continuity

Investigate uniform continuity of the following functions:
$$a) \ f(x)=\frac{1}{x} \\
b) \ f(x)=\cos \frac{1}{x}$$
How to deal with such questions, i have little knowledge about that topic thus i would appreciate detailed explanaitions.

EDIT: Will something change if i will define $f:(0,1)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: All you need is the definition of uniform continuity.  Write it down, think about it, use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function b is not uniform continious: Example $x_{n}=1/{(2\pi*n)}->0$
$y_{n}=2/{(\pi*n)}->0$ 
$f(x_{n})->1$ but $f(y_{n})->0$. b(x) is not continious, and then is not also uniform continous.
a) is not uniform continious see  page 2: http://www.math.ku.edu/~lerner/m500f09/Uniform%20continuity.pdf

Comment: ? Function b is not even defined at 0, much less continuous or uniformly continuous.

Comment: I agree. it's closure in 0 is whole ${0}\times[0,1]$Istn't it??

Comment: What if i will define $f:(0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ will this change something?

Comment: No because I can look for limit from right side. If you want for (0,1) we have: For $δ > 0$ pick n such that 1/(($\pi$- ½)n) and 1/(($\pi$ + ½)n) are <= than $δ/2$. 
Then we have that |1/(($\pi$ - ½)n) - 1/(($\pi$ + ½)n)|$ < δ$, but 
|f(1/(($\pi$ - ½)n)) - f(1/(($\pi$ + ½)n))| = 2 >= ε